# python list all vm with ip on vsphere

Tags: python-3.x, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm trying to get the vm name and ip from my vsphere server, currently I have only the name of the vm. How to get the ip?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, SmartConnectNoSSL, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import json

from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import ssl

# Get all the Vms from vCenter server inventory and print its name
# Below is Python 2.7.x code, which can be easily converted to python 3.x version

s=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
si= SmartConnectNoSSL(host="192.168.1.2", user="titi@gege.com", pwd="my_pass")
content=si.content

# Method that populates objects of type vimtype
def get_all_objs(content, vimtype):
        obj = {}
        container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, vimtype, True)
        for managed_object_ref in container.view:
                obj.update({managed_object_ref: managed_object_ref.name})
        return obj

#Calling above method
getAllVms=get_all_objs(content, [vim.VirtualMachine])

#Iterating each vm object and printing its name
for vm in getAllVms:
        print (vm.name)
```

Comment: Language improvement

Answer (score 1):

The IP address information for each VM is located in the [GuestInfo](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.vm.GuestInfo.html) object, which would be available at: `vm.guestinfo.ipaddress`

Note, the IP address returned is sourced from VMware Tools so make sure those are installed and running.

Comment: how cam i do it ?